# socat - UNIX-LISTEN and TCP-LISTEN in one command

Tags: port-forwarding, socat, unix-sockets

Is it possible, to open a tcp port and a socket with one process/command?

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock,fork,user=mysql,group=mysql,mode=777 TCP:123.123.123.1:3306
```

combined with:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:3306,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Finally i like to forward mysql

Comment: What do you mean when you say "combined" precisely? In any case, it is certainly possible to run the above two commands in separate shells but I can't see what you intend to do there. Connecting a MySQL socket to a remote MySQL socket won't do anything and MySQL comes with a TCP server anyway.